# Read characters from console, ignoring whitespaces and new lines

Tags: java, string, char, console-application, java.util.scanner

I have a question which is pretty easy to solve, yet not so.I am given an input for a game in which you have to read form the console.There are input commands: UP(U), DOWN(D), LEFT(L), RIGHT(R) coming in as a whole string ex: "RURD".
I have to break them down into characters.I did it by doing this:

```
    String ninja1Name = scanner.nextLine();
    String ninja2Name = scanner.nextLine();
    int[] arr = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

    Ninja ninja1 = new Ninja(ninja1Name);
    Ninja ninja2 = new Ninja(ninja2Name);

    Field field = new Field(ninja1, ninja2);
    field.createMatrix(arr[0], arr[1], scanner);

    //U, D, L, R -> directions to move(last lines of the input which I'm talking about)
    String tokens = scanner.nextLine();

    char[] commands = tokens.toCharArray();

    int currentCommandIndex = 0; // Initialization

    boolean gameEnded = false;

    while (!gameEnded) {
        char currentCommand = commands[currentCommandIndex];

        gameEnded = field.moveCurrentPlayer(currentCommand);

        currentCommandIndex++;
    }
```

the input is as follows:

Pesho - player 1(set from console using scanner)

Ivo - player 2(set from console using scanner)

3 3 - matrix dimensions(set from console using scanner)

PRA - first row of matrix(set from console using scanner)

B-B - second -//-(set from console using scanner)

RCI - third -//-(set from console using scanner)

LRRU - directions to go(set from console using scanner)

RD - second line of directions to go (set from console using scanner)

I want the scanner to read "LRRURD", not only "LRRU", then scan the second line, because there might be n lines of input.Basically I want to remove the whitespaces and new lines when reading from console, whilst reading multiple lines(making the new line concatinate to the previous one.

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Already answered on StackOverflow. This is among the most asked questions.

Comment: Can I have a link?Can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try replaceAll method

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   String originalStr = "this is some text";
   System.out.println("with out replaceAll method :- "+originalStr);
   originalStr = originalStr.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]", "");
   System.out.println("with replaceAll method :- "+originalStr);
 }
}
```

output

```
with out replaceAll method :- this is some text
with replaceAll method :- thisissometext
```